# Hover not working on AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have the below content that loads on through AJAX.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img alt="AlbumIcon" src="some-image.jpg">
        <div style="bottom:-75px;" class="meta">
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p class="genre"> <i class="icon-film icon-white"></i>
                Genre
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, I have writen the following script in jquery that applies to the above 'div.grid'.

```
 jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".grid").on({
            mouseenter : function () {
                $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                    bottom:'0px'
                },200);
            },

            mouseleave : function () {
                $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                    bottom:'-75px'
                },200);
            }
        });   
     });  
  });
```

The script works fine when the page loads the first time. However, the hover effect doesn't work once the above div is generated via AJAX after clicking on an 'a' tag. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here? New to all this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append these event handlers to dynamically generated elements, you need to bind to the `document` or another static parent element and then specify `.grid` as the second argument passed to `.on`.

The second argument is used as a filter to determine the selected elements that trigger the event.  So when the event is fired it will propagate to the `document` or parent element selected by jquery.  The event target will then be scrutinized using the selector provided as the second argument.  If the target matches the second argument, (`.grid` in our case), the event is fired.

You can read more in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Also, since your using `document.ready` there is no need for the short hand ready statement, `jquery(function($)`.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on({
                mouseenter : function () {
                    $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                        bottom:'0px'
                    },200);
                },

                mouseleave : function () {
                    $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                        bottom:'-75px'
                    },200);
                }
            }, ".grid");   
     });
```

Comment: @SunnyD I tried to give a better description, describing how propagation is handled.  Basically these events bubble up to the element we selected with jquery and then the target(element firing event) is inspected.

Comment: @SunnyD does that explanation help? Any further questions?

Comment: @SunnyD the documentation will explain it 10x better than me

Answer (score 0):

you lost your binding because of ajax that overwrite your div with class=".grid"
use parent element for binding

```
$('.ParentElementClass').on("mouseleave", ".grid", function(){...})
```

more from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're shooting for here but a little malformed HTML may have done it...

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/83zT4/)

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img alt="AlbumIcon" src="some-image.jpg" />
        <div style="bottom:-75px;" class="meta">
            <p class="title">Title</p>
            <p class="genre"><i class="icon-film icon-white"></i>Genre</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
     $(function () {
         $(".grid").on({
             mouseenter: function () {
                 alert('entered');
                 $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                     bottom: '0px'
                 }, 200);
             },

             mouseleave: function () {
                 alert('left');
                 $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                     bottom: '-75px'
                 }, 200);
             }
         }, ".thumb");
     });
 });
```

Be sure to close `img` tags. They're notorious for causing intermittent glitches.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `hover` function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid").hover(function () { /*mouseenter*/
            $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                bottom:'0px'
            },200);
        },function(){ /*mouseleave*/
            $(this).find('.meta').stop().animate({
                bottom:'-75px'
            },200);
        }
    });   
});
```

### Explanation:

The first parameter function does the work of `mouseenter` and the second does the work of `mouseleave`.

I'd recommend using those both, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in situation when you don't want an effect back when the user gets off his mouse from the element.

Comment: Well I did try using hover, but it never worked then. Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the above code will only work on a page load and not on AJAX invoked HTML.